# How to change color of specific cell's label in collection view from array of labels in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I'm pretty new to Swift and I have a question, I have a collection view, with a cell inside, and a label inside of this cell. I created an array and returned it, so I have multiple cells with labels. My question is, how to change a color of specific labels, for example if I want the labels "2", "7", "13"(from the image) and etc to be not green, but other color. THANK YOU
[screen of simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U1aC.png)

Comment: Set the label's color in the `cellForItemAt` method.

Answer (score 1):

Implement method below and set desired colour.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Access label of cell object and set desired colour
}
```

> Tells the delegate that the specified cell is about to be displayed in
>   the collection view.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview

Comment: Sorry, but how do I access label and set color?